# Java Android - Unable to start activity ComponentInfo, java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I am a total beginner on Android and Java. I have created a Currency Conversion app, which crashes when the device is rotated.

The original code:

```
package typeone.jiahuei.currencyconvert;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner unitSpinner;
private EditText amountEditText;
private String itemSelected;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    amountEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MainAct_InputEditText);
    unitSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.MainAct_unit_spinner);
    addItemsToUnitSpinner();
    addListenerToUnitSpinner();
    addListenerToAmountEditText();
}

private void addListenerToAmountEditText() {

    amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            addListenerToUnitSpinner();
            Quantity inputQuantity = new Quantity(getInputAmount(), Quantity.Unit.valueOf(itemSelected));
            updateTextViews(inputQuantity);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}


private void addItemsToUnitSpinner() {

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> unitSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.currency_type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    unitSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    unitSpinner.setAdapter(unitSpinnerAdapter);
}

private void addListenerToUnitSpinner() {

    unitSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            itemSelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Quantity inputQuantity = new Quantity(getInputAmount(), Quantity.Unit.valueOf(itemSelected));
            updateTextViews(inputQuantity);

            Resources res = getResources();
            String[] currencyNameArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.currency_name);
            String toastString = "Converting " + currencyNameArray[position];
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO lalala
        }
    });
}

private double getInputAmount() {
    String inputString = amountEditText.getText().toString();
    double inputAmount;

    if ( inputString.isEmpty() || inputString.equals(".") ) {
        inputAmount = 0;
    } else {
        inputAmount = Double.parseDouble(inputString);
    }
    return inputAmount;
}

private void updateTextViews(Quantity inputQuantity) {

    String currentViewName;
    for (Quantity.Unit unit : Quantity.Unit.values()) {
        currentViewName = unit.name() + "_TextView";
        int currentId = getResources().getIdentifier(currentViewName, "id",
                MainActivity.this.getPackageName());
        TextView currentTV = (TextView) findViewById(currentId);
        currentTV.setText(inputQuantity.toQuantity(unit).toString());
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

The Logs are:

```
10:44:19.769 32467-32467/typeone.jiahuei.currencyconvert E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: typeone.jiahuei.currencyconvert, PID: 32467
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{typeone.jiahuei.currencyconvert/typeone.jiahuei.currencyconvert.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
     at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:189)
     at typeone.jiahuei.currencyconvert.Quantity$Unit.valueOf(Quantity.java:13)
     at typeone.jiahuei.currencyconvert.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:50)
     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7991)
     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4345)
     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4199)
     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:84)
     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4174)
     at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:4067)
     at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:14746)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3127)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3127)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3127)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3127)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3127)
     at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:14724)
     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2035)
     at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1004)
     at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:959)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1163)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

After messing with the code for a few hours, I found that by changing to the code below, the error is solved.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner unitSpinner;
private EditText amountEditText;
private static String itemSelected;


private void addListenerToAmountEditText() {

    amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Quantity inputQuantity = new Quantity(getInputAmount(), Quantity.Unit.valueOf(MainActivity.itemSelected));
            updateTextViews(inputQuantity);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}
```

I only added *"static"* to the *String* variable at the beginning, and changed the *itemSelected* variable to *MainActivity.itemSelected*.

I just don't understand why the error occurred in the first place, and why making those changes can solve the issue?
The Unit is an enum in a Quantity class by the way.

Any answer is greatly appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

itemSelected is still null when you call onTextChanged

Comment: I am aware of that, but why is the String not null when it is first launched?
I tried calling the addListener method before calling onTextChanged, but it still return null (when I rotate the device).
Only after I made the variable into a static one the error is solved. Thanks

Comment: but you haven't trigger onItemSelected before onTextChanged

Comment: BTW just debug it: either add log, or breakpoints, and see in what order they're called and what are the different values at that point

Comment: I added _"static"_ to the _String_ variable at the beginning, and changed the _itemSelected_ variable in _onTextChanged_ to _MainActivity.itemSelected_, and the error went away. Can you enlighten me on how it solves the problem? I basically made that change based on a hunch.

Comment: I think that on rotation the onCreate is called, but for the reasons I told you it doesn't set the string. However before the orientation change some other action you might made did. When you set it to static, you probably saw the value that you set before the orientation change. While it might fix the crash in certain scenarios, it might also break things (you might see a wrong string there) and most importantly it probably doesn't fix the problem. IMHO it can still happen when you open the activity for the 1st time. That's why I suggest you to debug it

Comment: I am debugging it, and the problem is indeed that _itemSelected_ is null. So do you think that using _onSaveInstanceState_ to save the string, and then recovering it when it is being recreated will be a good way to solve the issue? Or is there any way to make sure _onItemSelected_ is triggered before _onTextChanged_?

Comment: No, IMHO it'll be still null when you enter the activity for the 1st time

Comment: I moved _addListener()_ (which has the _onTextChanged()_ method) to the end of the _onItemSelected()_ method body, hopefully that solves the issue. Thanks for your answers so much !